# How to access templateUrl for Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm sure this question is a layup, but I am having trouble accessing a templateUrl for an Angular directive. My project tree (minus irrelevant files) is as follows:

```
+---Scripts
|   |   Attempt2.js
|   
\---Views
    |   Target.html
    |   
    +---Account
    |       Login.cshtml
    |       Register.cshtml
    |       
    +---Home
    |       Index.cshtml
    |       
    \---RoutesDemo
            EditForm.cshtml
            One.cshtml
            Test.cshtml
            Three.cshtml
            Two.cshtml
```

How would one access `Target.html` from `Attempt2.js`?

Comment: what is exactly your aim?

Comment: To be able to have a template for displaying data received from a controller. I am trying to keep `Attempt2.js` as simple as possible; it is merely where I attach components from different files to the application. So in an effort to maintain cleanliness, I don't want extensive HTML in `Attempt2.js`.